# Python's subprocess module hangs when pipe is too big

Tags: python, linux, pipe, subprocess, popen

This command causes Python 3.5 in RedHat linux to hang indefinitely for me:

```
import shapely.geometry
```

After hitting Ctrl+C, I tracked it down to this code in "/lib/python3.5/ctypes/util.py" that hangs on the subprocess.Popen part:

```
try:
    with subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/ldconfig', '-p'],
                          stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          env={'LC_ALL': 'C', 'LANG': 'C'}) as p:
        res = re.search(regex, p.stdout.read())
        if res:
            return os.fsdecode(res.group(1))
except OSError:
            pass
```

After reading [this article](https://thraxil.org/users/anders/posts/2008/03/13/Subprocess-Hanging-PIPE-is-your-enemy/) I ran this:

```
$ldconfig -p
```

and I indeed got a big list returned that I think is overflowing the pipe, causing python to hang.

My question is: What's the right way to fix this? For now I made a monkey patch of util.py to quickly work around, but it doesn't fix the root cause.

```
try:
    raise(OSError) # I added this to avoid the stuff below from hanging!
    with subprocess.Popen(['/sbin/ldconfig', '-p'],
                          stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                          env={'LC_ALL': 'C', 'LANG': 'C'}) as p:
        res = re.search(regex, p.stdout.read())
        if res:
            return os.fsdecode(res.group(1))
except OSError:
            pass
```